# Oracle Case statement not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use the following case statement to extract information from my table, if I ignore the case statement and manually enter the day it works, but the case statement doesn't it just seems to jump directly to the else part, any suggestions please?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day = CASE WHEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'DAY') = 'SATURDAY' THEN 'Sat'
                                       WHEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY' THEN 'Sun'
                                       ELSE 'weekday' END;
```

Comment: Please show the the table and sample data.

Comment: Oracle provides `FMDAY`, which will take care of the blank padding. Also, it is NLS dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the to_char function is padding the string with a space at the end, and it does not match.  I tried this:

```
select '#' || to_char(SYSDATE+2, 'DAY') || '#' from dual
```

and it returned: `#SUNDAY   #`

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE day = CASE WHEN trim(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY' THEN 'Sat'
                                       WHEN trim(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN 'Sun'
                                       ELSE 'weekday' END;
```

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) it states that for "DAY" - Name of day, padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of day in the date language used for this element.

Not what I expected.

Comment: Use the `FM` modifier to get rid of the spaces: `to_char(SYSDATE+2, 'FMday')`

Comment: Also, to note that it is NLS dependent. It won't return **SATURDAY** for `FRENCH`, will work in `ENGLISH`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note:

1. There is no need to `TRIM` the blank padding manually. Oracle provides `FM` i.e. Fill Mode format to get rid of the blank padding.
2. You should mention the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` explicitly since the format is **NLS dependent**.

From Oracle documentation on [Format Model Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) :

> FM
>
> Fill mode. Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes to
>   fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the
>   display width of the largest element for the relevant format model:
>
> - Numeric elements are padded with leading zeros to the width of the maximum value allowed for the element. For example, the YYYY element
>     is padded to four digits (the length of '9999'), HH24 to two digits
>     (the length of '23'), and DDD to three digits (the length of '366').
> - The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the
>     longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name, or the
>     longest abbreviated day name, respectively, among valid names
>     determined by the values of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and NLS_CALENDAR
>     parameters. For example, when NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE is AMERICAN and
>     NLS_CALENDAR is GREGORIAN (the default), the largest element for MONTH
>     is SEPTEMBER, so all values of the MONTH format element are padded to
>     nine display characters. The values of the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and
>     NLS_CALENDAR parameters are specified in the third argument to TO_CHAR
>     and TO_* datetime functions or they are retrieved from the NLS
>     environment of the current session.
> - The character element RM is padded with trailing blanks to the length of 4, which is the length of 'viii'.
> - Other character elements and spelled-out numbers (SP, SPTH, and THSP suffixes) are not padded.
>
> The FM modifier suppresses the above padding in the return value of
>   the TO_CHAR function.

So, you could use `FMDAY` instead of `DAY` format to get rid of the **blank padding**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT '#' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'fmDAY') || '#' as dt FROM dual;

DT
-----------
#SATURDAY#

SQL>
```

So, you could modify your case statement as:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMDAY') = 'SATURDAY'
  4      THEN 'Sat'
  5      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMDAY') = 'SUNDAY'
  6      THEN 'Sun'
  7      ELSE 'weekday'
  8    END as day
  9  FROM dual;

DAY
-------
Sat

SQL>
```

Use **NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**

For example,

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='french';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT '#' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'fmDAY') || '#' as dt FROM dual;

DT
----------
#SAMEDI#

SQL>
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='english';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT '#' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'fmDAY') || '#' as dt FROM dual;

DT
-----------
#SATURDAY#

SQL>
```

So, you need to mention it at individual statement level:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SATURDAY'
  4      THEN 'Sat'
  5      WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUNDAY'
  6      THEN 'Sun'
  7      ELSE 'weekday'
  8    END AS DAY
  9  FROM dual;

DAY
-------
Sat

SQL>
```